# Publish post on Facebook with text, image and app link

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application there is a user feed. I want to add a share with Facebook feature to allow users share posts from my app in their Facebook wall.
Posts to share have text and image. Also I would like to add a link to my app in Facebook posts shared from my app.

First attempt was make a share using `UIActivityViewController`. The problem is that it doesn't allow to pre-fill text in share dialog. So user should retype post content and this is not an option.

Now I'm implementing this feature by using Graph API - ask for publish permissions and make a call to `me/feed`.

To connect Facebook posts wit my app I created an App Link and added it to published posts. When user grabs the link he is forwarded to app store or app is opened.

Parameters I pass in `me/feed` request:

```
let params = [
    "message" : post.text,
    "link" : "https://fb.me/9999999999999999",
    "name" : "App Name",
    "caption" : "Link Caption",
]
```

It works like I wish.

The problem is how to add in this Facebook post url to image as my posts have image (and probably a video in the feature)?

Thank you for help

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message in posts/shares made via API either. The whole content of the message parameter has to be entered by the user of your app. No pre-filling, no appending hashtags/URLs to it automatically by your app.

Comment: ok, so what is correct way to share the content from my app in Facebook and add a back link to my app. How this works in other apps? The only idea I have now is to duplicate my content from app in web and share a link to web version of post. Are better ideas without web version?

Comment: You need something on the web to link to. You can embed [App Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks) there, if you want to link users that already have your app installed to a specific point within your app, or the app store. You can also create app links via API, and then get a URL to link to, if you don’t want to host the content yourself.